# 10m Resolution Seamless Dataset

Tags: dem

I'm looking for a seamless 10m (1/3 arc second) dataset on a state by state basis. Is there a resource that houses this. I am trying to run a slope and aspect analysis for a variety of states but do not have the resources to download each tile and mosaic them into a seamless raster.

Comment: If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Where on the earth?

Answer (score -1):

Check out the USGS National Elevation Dataset (NED).  Not all the states have 10-meter coverage yet, but many do.